# How to document custom REST API in Salesforce

Tags: api, apexrest, documentation

I am currently working on a project where we will integrate salesforce with a couple of other tools in the company's processes. For doing so, I will develop a lot of endpoints (20-30 ressources, I guess).

Now I was wondering: How to best document all my API endpoints? I do a lot of my technical documentation in Confluence+JIRA and have not that much routine in working with APIs (I know about tools like Swagger or Apiary, though). Is there a better approach to do that for salesforce APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Salesforce but salesforce does not provide any native tooling to document your Custom REST API .Instead I would explore [Swagger](https://swagger.io/getting-started/) to assist me with the tooling .

Swagger Editor is commonly used by most of the open source projects to document the API with sample request and response structures .

Comment: Swagger *IS* awesome!

Comment: Thank you very much. This will be especially usefull, when we want to document our enterprise API in general and not only my very personal salesforce APIs.

Comment: I decided to use a combination of 10% confluence and 90% swagger. I do the complete technical documentation in swagger and confluence holds the road map, my general concepts and requirements. I am very happy with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to document APIs (mostly REST for me...), and I do it in Confluence. It's typically based on a table with headers like:

- resource
- version
- URI
- HTTP method
- description
- example

You might want others...

The *win* for the API consumers (the thing they like the BEST), is that the example column has a link to another page. On those example pages there are Code block macros with additional details of what needs to be in the request body, and the JSON returned. I get the return JSON by using the REST explorer in Workbench... copy/paste the raw response.

Anyway that's what I do....

Bonus points: The REST explorer is also a GREAT way to perform a functional test of your new custom Apex REST resource!